# how to delete certain number of rows based on a conditional expression?

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I have 'imbalanced data' problem. There are 99% of yes and 1% of no in binary classification. Here, I would like to delete certain number of rows that indicate yes = 1 to balance out data proportion. But as I am not deep in python, I only am able to delete the whole rows that indicate the condition. 
Can anyone suggest syntax for let's say, 'deleting only 10000 rows that are yes = 1' from my dataframe?

Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select top index values and [`DataFrame.drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) them:

```
np.random.seed(2019)
N = 20
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.random.choice([0,1], N)})

#remove top 5 values matched condition
M = 5
idx = df.index.values[df['a'] == 1][:M]

df = df.drop(idx)
print (df)
    a
0   0
1   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  0
15  0
16  1
17  1
18  0
19  0
```

Another solution is create mask by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), chain by inverse mask with `~` and filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
M = 5
mask = (df['a'] == 1)
df = df[(mask.cumsum() > M) | ~mask]
print (df)
    a
0   0
1   0
4   0
5   0
6   0
7   0
10  0
11  0
12  0
13  0
15  0
16  1
17  1
18  0
19  0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way to do this is

```
df.drop(df.query('col == 1').sample(n = 10000).index)
```

where 'col' is the column with values 0 or 1.